# Django + MySQL 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime

I tried to login admin page, but this error was shown...

Connect MySQL and Django

Using Engine mysql.connector.django.
(Othere Engine can not connect mysql :( i tried..)

Migrate was success.

```
AttributeError at /admin/login/
'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 2.0.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'
```

My pip freeze is here.

```
certifi==2018.4.16
Django==2.0.5
mysql-connector-python==8.0.11
mysqlclient==1.3.12
pipenv==2018.5.18
psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
PyMySQL==0.8.1
pytz==2018.4
virtualenv==16.0.0
virtualenv-clone==0.3.0
whitenoise==3.3.1
```

I guess that MySQL is not support the latest django version, is it?

All traceback is here!!

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'picker_main']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in login
  398.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in dispatch
  66.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  141.         if form.is_valid():

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  179.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  174.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  377.         self._clean_form()

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _clean_form
  404.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py" in clean
  195.             self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in authenticate
  70.             user = _authenticate_with_backend(backend, backend_path, request, credentials)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in _authenticate_with_backend
  116.     return backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py" in authenticate
  16.             user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in get_by_natural_key
  44.         return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  397.         num = len(clone)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  254.         self._fetch_all()

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
  1179.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __iter__
  62.         for row in compiler.results_iter(results):

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in apply_converters
  1005.         for row in map(list, rows):

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in cursor_iter
  1460.         for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <lambda>
  1460.         for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in inner
  96.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py" in fetchmany
  510.             rows.extend(self._cnx.get_rows(size))

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py" in get_rows
  275.                                                           row[i])

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py" in to_python
  205.             return self._cache_field_types[vtype[1]](value, vtype)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py" in _DATETIME_to_python
  119.         dt = MySQLConverter._DATETIME_to_python(self, value)

File "C:\Users\XSHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py" in _DATETIME_to_python
  506.             (date_, time_) = value.split(b' ')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: I suggest you start by cleaning up your environment, you say you are using 1 connector, you have 4

Comment: @diek Thanks to comment! But.. can I ask what is connector? I guess...I use mysql connector. And other connectors are pymysql, mysqlclient... and another is,,?

Comment: @diek Oh...I finished cleaning connector, and I install mysqlconnector-python. But until same error...:(

Comment: What view are you using for the `/admin/login/` url?

Comment: @JohnGordon just view to admin page! First started django project, second connected mysql, third created superuser, and login error...

Comment: I fixed some error.. `value = str(value.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))` `(date_, time_) = value.split(' ')` But another error showed...`must be str or None, not bytes (field b'date_joined')`

Comment: The recommended choice from Django is https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/